# Problems with multiple actions in a JSF page

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5 web application which contains an .xhtml with multiple possible outcomes:

```
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function download(file) {

            document.forms[0].elements["filename"].value = file;
            document.forms[0].submit();

        }

        function back() {

            document.forms[0].method = "get";
            document.forms[0].action = "home.xhtml";
            document.forms[0].submit();

        }
    </script>
    <form id="download" action="DownloadServlet" method="post">
         . . . .
           <h:commandButton id="back" value="Back" onclick="back();" />
           <h:commandButton id="download" value="Download" type="Submit"
                            onclick="download('#{value}');" />




    </form>
```

By clicking on the "Download" button, the Servlet "DownloadServlet" kicks in and downloads a file selected in the form.
However by clicking on the Back button, I'm not redirected to the page "home.xhtml". The Javascript function "back" simply is not invoked but the Servlet kicks again. It seems a conflict between the two actions. How can I solve it and add a button to return to another page ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it the hard way. Use a `<h:button>` to generate a GET button.

```
<h:button id="back" value="Back" outcome="home.xhtml" />
```

The second `<h:commandButton>` could better be just a plain vanilla `<input type="submit">`, by the way.

Comment: Awesome! The second change was not necessary though.

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed not necessary, but it's in turn unnecessary to use a JSF command component while the HTML equivalent could do it in a simpler and less confusing way, because you're nowhere using a JSF form with a JSF managed bean.